# What does it mean for a "bad eye" to "touch" something?

Tags: meaning, poetry, uyghur-language, drops-of-melodies, hemirah-tohti

The poem *Dance in Heytkah* reads as follows,

> 12th September - Kurban Eid
> I saw the dance of Sama
> In the modern world 
> Magic mirror on the wall 
> My beloved hometown 
> Kashgar
> From ancient history fill now 
> The sama happens in Atekar
> Filled with vibrance
> I pass by
> And see the beautiful view
> And it brings me to my youth
> I see myself
> Among the dance
> Tears dropping with happiness 
> Yet so much joy in me 
> My heaven - my beloved hometown 
> Kashgar
> I missed you dearly
> You are the centre of the Silk Road 
> You you the pram 
> Cradled arts of all
> What a treasure - tradition 
> Inherited by you
> Wish you a thousand years
> Of happiness like this
> No bad eye may touch you
> My dear hometown 
> Kashgar

What does he mean by "no bad eye may touch you" in this context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we interpret the poem as attempting to personify Kashgar, I think *may no evil eye touch you* might be a better translation; otherwise, *may no villainous gaze land upon you* would be suitable.

In Asian cultures, including the Turkic one from which the Uyghurs originate,  blessings like "may you remain safe from the evil eye" are frequent, as are preventative measures to ward off gazes with designs treacherous or lecherous.

Persecution of the Uyghurs has found expression in policies that have aimed to destroy parts of Kashgar, a place historically important for the Uyghurs; it's a form of cultural genocide. See "[Kashgar's Old City Destruction Emblematic of Beijing’s Cultural Campaign Against Uyghurs](https://www.rfa.org/english/news/uyghur/destruction-06052020164031.html)", "[Kashgar: Images of Demolition from the Cradle of Uyghur Culture](https://uhrp.org/kashgar-project/)," and "[Demolishing Kashgar's History](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/demolishing-kashgars-history-7324895/)".

Thus Tohti is wishing for her "beloved hometown" to remain free and safe, capable of providing future generations with memories as dear as those she was able to make.

Answer (score 9):

This is an elaboration of, not a substitute for, @CDR's accurate answer. The last few sentences of the poem use expressions common in many Asian cultures for wishing longevity to something or (more commonly) someone cherished:

> Wish you a thousand years
> Of happiness like this
> No bad eye may touch you
> My dear hometown
> Kashgar

*No bad eye may touch you* is literal, but somewhat inept; a better translation would be something like *May you be safe from envious glances*. Particularly when someone is being praised, it is common to use this form of words immediately after.

The idea is that (for example) if I see a baby and say something like, "What a cute child!," the compliment might cause others to look toward the baby with envy. Someone might overhear me, look at the baby, and think: "I hope that baby gets a scar so that everyone recognizes *my* baby as the cute one!" It is common in some cultures to put a black smudge on babies' faces to disguise their cuteness and thus ward off such envious thoughts. Or (to take another example), if I get an A minus on an exam and you get an A, when I say, "Congratulations!," my compliment might be tinged with envy. I could perhaps be secretly wishing that you fall ill on the day of the next exam so I will do better. I am regarding your success *with a bad eye*.

So a sincere well-wisher of yours may add something like **chashm-e-badduur**, "evil eyes, begone!" It would not be considered impugning my motives for that sincere well-wisher to say that, because the conventional interpretation would be that said well-wisher is guarding against someone *else*, such as an evil djinn, who might get jealous on hearing my compliment, not against *my* possible jealousy. So even if the sincere well-wisher *does* suspect me of envying your better grade, I have no grounds to take offense.

So common is the superstition of the evil eye, it's often used as an explanation for a calamity. Say if a handsome and successful young man is cut down in his prime due to illness or an accident, people might say *Someone's [evil] gaze fell on him*. It's not that people necessarily believe the superstition; it's merely a ritualized utterance, the way many otherwise rational people in the West will say "knock wood" (while rapping their foreheads with their knuckles) after talking of anticipated good fortune. It's the same idea: the knocking will drive away evil spirits who could be envious.

It's therefore common for people *giving* compliments to immediately follow up with this phrase to ward off the evil eye, both to indicate their own sincerity and to protect the person being complimented from the envy of others. So in context, the poet is singing Kashgar's praises. All his talk of Kashgar's beauty and glory might very well bring bad luck to the city, as potential conquerors or rival cities might start plotting its destruction. The poet therefore follows up his compliments with conventional phrases asking that the city prosper for æons (*Wish you a thousand years / of happiness like this*) and be kept safe from envious eyes of those who wish evil upon it (*No bad eye may touch you*).

Finally, why is this *bad eye* said to *touch*? This phrasing comes from now-superseded [emission theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emission_theory_(vision)), which held that visual perception occurs when beams from the eye fall upon the object looked at. It's a short step from the idea that sight involves something from my eye touching what I'm looking at, to the idea that looking with envy damages the object of my envy. Again, the persistence of the phrasing *May no evil gaze touch you* doesn't necessarily indicate that emission theory is still believed in those cultures. It was after all an Arab philosopher, [Ibn al-Haytham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_al-Haytham), who propounded the current theory of optics some ten centuries ago. But we still use phrases like *my gaze fell on him* or *it caught my eye* all the time, without necessarily believing that something from our eyes has literally fallen or gotten caught.